# CSS animation on hover sometimes work other doesn't

Tags: css

This is my HTML:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <figure align="center"><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/or-site.jpg" alt=""><br><span>WEBSITE RESPONSIVO EM HTML5 PARA <br> A EMPRESA OR LEDS</span></figure>
    <figure align="center"><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/or-cat.jpg" alt=""><br><span>CATÁLOGO DE PRODUTOS FEITO PARA A <br> EMPRESA OR LEDS</span></figure>
    <figure align="center"><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/cci.jpg" alt=""><br><span>WEBSITE PARA O CENTRO CULTURAL <br> ISRAELITA (CCI)</span></figure><br>
    <figure align="center"><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/cartazes.jpg" alt=""><br><span>CARTAZES PUBLICITÁRIOS PARA O CENTRO <br> CULTURAL RAV KOOK</span></figure>
    <figure align="center"><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/padronagem.jpg" alt=""><br><span>PADRONAGENS FEITAS PARA A DISCIPLINA <br> "DESENVOLVIMENTO DE PADRONAGENS"</span></figure>
    <figure><img src="http://www.felipegrin.com/port/animacao.jpg" alt=""><br><span>ANIMAÇÃO FEITA PARA A DISCIPLINA <br> "ANIMAÇÃO PARA COMPUTAÇÃO"</span></figure>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper figure {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper figure::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
     -moz-transform: skewX(-25deg);
      -ms-transform: skewX(-25deg);
       -o-transform: skewX(-25deg);
          transform: skewX(-25deg);
}

.wrapper figure:hover::before {
  -webkit-animation: shine .77s;
     -moz-animation: shine .77s;
       -o-animation: shine .77s;
          animation: shine .77s;
}

.wrapper figure img {
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper figure span {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #3dadc7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5e5dooqp/), the animation on hover seems to work on the first time you hover at each image, but when you retry to hover, sometimes it just doesn't work! This is really strange and i can't see why sometimes would work and other don't!

Answer (score 0):

The animation is used in the `figure` tag. The `span` that you use as description is inside your `figure` tag. So, when you hover the image, but let your mouse on the description, you dont fire another on hover event. The animation the just dont fire.
Try to use a `img` tag to hold the image itself, and put the animation in the `img` tag, not the `figure`.

Comment: It's not the span that's causing the problem. I tried deleting all of them, leaving just the images. The bug was still there.